# Using long lists as map keys in Java

Tags: java, list, design-patterns, collections, dictionary

I plan to use a map where keys are rather long list (~10/100k of small elements):

```
Map<List<K>, V> myMap = new HashMap<List<K>, V>();
```

The default `List::hashCode()` implementation (in AbstractList) compute it's hashcode value using the hashcode of all the list elements, in a loop. Also the `List::equals()` method compare all list elements in turn, and return false for the first element which differs.

This all makes senses, except that the list hashcode value **is not cached** (JDK 6) and thus re-computed everytime, which make this usage pattern really inefficient (map rely on hashcode quite often). There would be less issue for the `equals()` as distinct elements would have on average a first different item at a rather low index, so the loop would break early (but have to compare all elements for same lists).

I was thinking of encapsulating my list with a new custom `KeyList` class keeping the hashcode value in cache to increase performance, but:

1. This is not trivial as you have to take care of synchronization issues and implementing some of the list interface methods;
2. It's intrusive as you have to use this decorator in the client code;
3. This does not solve the `equals()` performance issue when comparing identical elements.

Would there be a better idea of handling this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this case, your lists must be *immutable*, otherwise the `hashCode()` would change over time which would corrupt the hash map. If the list is immutable, you can compute the `hashCode()` once and use that as key wrapped in a `Long` object.

If you insist on using the List interface for key, you should implement the `KeyList` you mentioned. Simply create a List implementation that delegates to the original List but overrides the hashCode() to return the memoized value which can be initialized in the constructor.

```
public abstract static class MemoizedHashCodeList<K> implements List<K>{
    private final long hashCode;
    private final List<K> delegate;
    public MemoizedHashCodeList(List<K> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        hashCode = delegate.hashCode();
    }

    /* Rest of the List<K> implementation */
}
```

To speed up the implementation, you can use Google Guava's `ForwardingList` class that implements the delegation pattern for you.

But most importantly, make sure that your lists are immutable. Don't try to ruin your code with synchronization on mutable lists, it just won't work.

Comment: My list are indeed immutable. If I use the list hashcode value as a key, the potential for collision is too high (32 bits only), so I can't use your suggestion. Even with large checksum I can't take the risk of running into a collision.

Comment: If you reuse the same List objects everywhere, then use IdentitiyMap instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best solution would be a KeyList class. I suggest isolating the class of the key lists to one method, and having client code request a List reference from that method. Everywhere else, it can just be referenced as a List.

Assuming the key lists are immutable, which they need to be for use as Map keys, you only need to synchronize on calculating the hash code. Or even skip that, and copy the way String creates its hash code.

In addition to the standard hash code, which is only 32 bits, you could perhaps add a more powerful hash that has a very low collision probability, and compare those rather than doing an element-by-element comparison of the list. Using your own KeyList class allows overriding equals, as well as hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refactor the code and create a separate object to use as a key. You can do something almost anything to create a unique key, perhaps keeps the lists in an array and use the array index, or calculate the hashcode of the list and use keep that as the key. But it is very unusual to keep large objects as keys and I recommend that you do not do that.